# Why the tree is not a binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I am a beginner in the field of data structures, I am studying binary trees and in my textbook there's a tree which is not a binary tree but I am not able to make out why the tree is not a binary tree because every node in the tree has atmost two children.
According to Wikipedia definition of binary tree is "In computer science, a binary tree is a treedata structure in which each node has at most two children, which are referred to as the left child and the right child."
The tree in the picture seems to satisfy the condition as mentioned in the definition of binary tree.
I want an explanation for why the tree is not a binary tree?[image: tree]

Comment: Read the definition and explanation here http://btechsmartclass.com/DS/U3_T3.html

Comment: For a binary tree, there is always just one path between root and any other node. In your case you have to paths from root to node `I`.

Comment: @Sirko can I the source of your definition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [cs.se] instead.

Comment: Stack overflow is for programming related questions and programming is computer science, then why??

Comment: @ashwiniabhishek a similar definition can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Rooted_tree

Comment: I have added the answer,I ask the question because the data given in the book itself was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, This not even a tree because a tree is connected acyclic graph also a binary tree is a finite set of elements that is either empty or is partitioned into three disjoint subsets. The first subset contains a single element called the root of the tree. The other two subsets are themselves binary trees called the left and right subtrees of the original tree.
Here the word disjoint answers the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not even a tree, let alone binary tree. Node I has two parents which violates the tree property.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a binary tree because of node I

This can be ABEI or ACFI

This would mean the node can be represented by 2 binary numbers which is incorrect

Each node has either 0 or 1 parents. 0 in the case of the root node. 1 otherwise. I has 2 parents E and F